# osql does not execute query

Tags: sql-server, osql

I have a system where I only have osql available (SQL2K Express).
I execute queries and at one moment it stopped displaying any results. It seems that actually it does not execute the queries (because an erroneous script does not show an error).
I do:

```
osql -E
use <dbname>;
go;
select top 1 * from SomeTable;
go;
```

If I write "go" without the training ";", is displays one error for each time I written a "go" without the training ";" during current "session";

Restarting osql does not help.

Any clue anyone?

Thanks,
florin

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a "reset" command in osql. Using it makes it work again.
Don't know what actually caused it to have that behavior in the 1st place.
Next time I will RTFM...

Comment: this worked for me: 

osql -E use <dbname>; go select top 1 * from SomeTable; go

the error is that go does not need a semicolon, not sure what you mean by reset tho.